# How to import a part of an Excel file?

Tags: matrix, import, excel

I'm trying to import a part of an excel, the column 20 and the row between 6-59 in this column.
I tried :

```
tab = Import[
   "file.xlsx"];
time = tab[[20, 6 ;; 59]]
```

and

```
time = Import[
  "D:\Users\martine\Desktop\data\KP\Results largest GFP area \
mean.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {6;; 59}, {20}}]
time = Import[
  "D:\Users\martine\Desktop\data\KP\Results largest GFP area \
mean.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {6:59}, {20}}]
```

But it doesn't work so apparently I didn't write it the right way.

Thank you in  advance

Comment: try `{"Data", 1, 6;; 59, {20}}`?

Comment: it works ! that was the only one I had not tried !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the braces around `Span` in the second argument of `Import`, that is, use

```
{"Data", 1, 6;;59, {20}}
```